# When do I need to cache the data accessed from DB?

Tags: mysql, architecture, microservices, system-design

I have a bit theoretical question.

I have a microservice which handles 200/300 req/sec on peak. In each request we make several calls to DB (MySQL) and return some information.

Given the RPS, does it make sense to cache the data on app level?

Or modern MySQL servers can easily withstand such load and use their own Db-level cache instead?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the complexity of the queries, so it's impossible to give a general answer. You'll need to benchmark it yourself.

Comment: I can DOS a database server with one query. Or we can run 100,000 queries per second. Depends on the type of queries, the server horsepower, the volume of data, other load on the database server, and many other factors. I don't think there's a way anyone can answer your question in the general case. Caching is often a good idea, but it adds complexity to your application. Almost every type of optimization adds complexity.

Comment: If you use "serverless" databases in cloud environments, those can stretch to take even extreme workloads. Or you can quickly spin up multiple database instances using replicated data to handle peaks in workloads.